# Why does casting Double.NaN to int not throw an exception in Java?

Tags: java, casting, floating-point, ieee-754

So I know the IEEE 754 specifies some special floating point values for values that are not real numbers.  In Java, casting those values to a primitive `int` does **not** throw an exception like I would have expected.  Instead we have the following:

```
int n;
n = (int)Double.NaN; // n == 0
n = (int)Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY; // n == Integer.MAX_VALUE
n = (int)Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY; // n == Integer.MIN_VALUE
```

What is the rationale for **not** throwing exceptions in these cases?  Is this an IEEE standard, or was it merely a choice by the designers of Java?  Are there bad consequences that I am unaware of if exceptions would be possible with such casts?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> What is the rationale for not throwing exceptions in these cases?

I imagine that the reasons include:

- These are edge cases, and are likely to occur rarely in applications that do this kind of thing.
- The behavior is not "totally unexpected".
- When an application casts from a double to an int, significant loss of information is expected.  The application is either going to ignore this possibility, or the cast will be preceded by checks to guard against it ... which could also check for these cases.
- No other double / float operations result in exceptions, and (IMO) it would be a bit schizophrenic to do it in this case.
- There could possibly be a performance hit ... on some hardware platforms (current or future).

A commentator said this:

> *"I suspect the decision to not have the conversion throw an exception was motivated by a strong desire to avoid throwing exceptions for any reasons, for fear of forcing code to add it to a throws clause."*

I don't think that is a plausible explanation:

- The Java language designers<sup>1</sup> don't have a mindset of avoiding throwing exceptions "for any reason".  There are numerous examples in the Java APIs that demonstrate this.
- The issue of the `throws` clause is addressed by making the exception unchecked.  Indeed, many related exceptions like `ArithmeticException` or `ClassCastException` are declared as unchecked for this reason.

> Is this an IEEE standard, or was it merely a choice by the designers of Java?

The latter, I think.

> Are there bad consequences that I am unaware of if exceptions would be possible with such casts?

None apart from the obvious ones ...

(But it is not really relevant.  The JLS and JVM spec say what they say, and changing them would be liable to break existing code.  And it is not just Java code we are talking about now ...)

---

I've done a bit of digging.  A lot of the x86 instructions that could be used convert from double to integers seem to generate hardware interrupts ... unless masked.  It is not clear (to me) whether the specified Java behavior is easier or harder to implement than the alternative suggested by the OP.

---

<sup>1 - I don't dispute that some Java programmers *do* think this way.  But they were / are not the Java designers, and this question is asking specifically about the Java design rationale.</sup>

Comment: I suspect the decision to not have the conversion throw an exception was motivated by a strong desire to avoid throwing exceptions for any reasons, for fear of forcing code to add it to a `throws` clause.  From a practical perspective, however, if code tries to convert a floating-point number to an integer and it doesn't fit, the code is unlikely to work correctly and so an exception is probably better than carrying on with bogus data.

Comment: The (hypothetical) exception would not need to be a *checked* exception.  In fact, that would be a mistake.  But either way, this is not going to happen.

Answer (score 10):

> What is the rationale for not throwing
>   exceptions in these cases? Is this an
>   IEEE standard, or was it merely a
>   choice by the designers of Java?

The [IEEE 754-1985](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=30711) Standard in pages 20 and 21 under the sections 2.2.1 NANs and 2.2.2 Infinity clearly explains the reasons why NAN and Infinity values are required by the standard. Therefore this not a Java thing.

The [Java Virtual Machine Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/) in section [3.8.1 Floating Point Arithmetic and IEEE](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Overview.doc.html#35257) 754 states that when conversions to integral types are carried out then the JVM will apply rounding toward zero which explains the results you are seeing.

The standard does mention a feature named "trap handler" that could be used to determine when overflow or NAN occurs but the Java Virtual Machine Specification clearly states this is not implemented for Java. It says in section 3.8.1:

> The floating-point operations of the
>   Java virtual machine do not throw
>   exceptions, trap, or otherwise signal
>   the IEEE 754 exceptional conditions of
>   invalid operation, division by zero,
>   overflow, underflow, or inexact. The
>   Java virtual machine has no signaling
>   NaN value.

So, the behavior is not unspecified regardless of consequences.

> Are there bad consequences that I am
>   unaware of if exceptions would be
>   possible with such casts?

Understanding the reasons stated in standard should suffice to answer this question. The standard explains with exhaustive examples the consequences you are asking for here. I would post them, but that would be too much information here and the examples can be impossible to format appropriately in this edition tool.

**EDIT**

I was reading the latest maintenance review of the [Java Virtual Machine Specification](http://cds.sun.com/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/CDS-CDS_JCP-Site/en_US/-/USD/VerifyItem-Start/jvm-javase7-mr3-spec.pdf?BundledLineItemUUID=7CiJ_hCxGQ0AAAEvXzEWpsrG&OrderID=DE2J_hCxnKcAAAEvTDEWpsrG&ProductID=ShWJ_hCyrMkAAAEvsYQHenE_&FileName=/jvm-javase7-mr3-spec.pdf) as published recently by the JCP as part of their work on [JSR 924](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/summary?id=924) and in the section 2.11.14 named type conversion istructions contains some more information that could help you in your quest for answers, not yet what you are looking for, but I believe it helps a bit. It says:

> In a narrowing numeric conversion of a
>   floating-point value to an integral
>   type T, where T is either int or long,
>   the floating-point value is converted
>   as follows:
>
> - If the floating-point value is NaN,    the result of the conversion is an
>     int or  long 0.
> - Otherwise, if the floating-point    value is not an infinity, the
>     floating-point value  is rounded to
>     an integer value V using IEEE 754
>     round towards zero mode.
>
> There are two cases:
>
> - If T is long and this integer value    can be represented as a long, then
>     the result is the long value V.
> - If T is of type int and this integer    value can be represented as
>     an int,    then the result is the int
>     value V.
>
> Otherwise:
>
> - Either the value must be too small (a    negative value of large
>     magnitude or     negative infinity),
>     and the result is    the smallest
>     representable value of    type  int or
>     long.
> - Or the value must be too large (a    positive value of large magnitude or
>     posi- tive infinity), and the result
>     is the largest representable value of 
>     type int or  long.
>
> A narrowing numeric conversion from
>   double to float behaves in accordance
>   with IEEE 754. The result is correctly
>   rounded using IEEE 754 round to
>   nearest mode. A value too small to be
>   represented as a float is converted to
>   a positive or negative zero of type
>   float; a value too large to be
>   represented as a float is converted to
>   a positive or negative infinity. A
>   double NaN is always converted to
>   a float NaN.
>
> Despite the fact that overflow,
>   underflow, or loss of precision
>   may occur, narrowing conversions among
>   numeric types never cause the
>   Java virtual machine to throw a
>   runtime exception (not to be confused
>   with an IEEE 754 floating-point
>   exception).

I know this simply restates what you already know, but it has a clue, it appears that the IEEE standard has a requirement of rounding to the nearest. Perhaps there you can find the reasons for this behavior.

**EDIT**

The IEEE Standard in question in section 2.3.2 Rounding Modes States:

> By
>   default, rounding means round toward
>   the
>   nearest. The standard requires that three other
>   rounding modes be provided; namely, round toward
>   0, round toward +Infinity and round toward –Infinity.
>
> When used with the convert to integer operation, round toward –Infinity causes the convert to become the floor function, whereas, round toward +Infinity
>   is ceiling.
>
> The mode rounding affects overflow because when round toward O or round toward
>   -Infinite is in effect, an overflow of positive magnitude causes the default result to be the largest representable number, not +Infinity.
>
> Similarly, overflows of
>   negative magnitude will produce
>   the largest negative number when round toward +Infinity or round toward O is in effect.

Then they proceed to mention an example of why this is useful in interval arithmetic. Not sure, again, that this is the answer you are looking for, but it can enrich your search.

Comment: It seems like you are pointing to the IEEE standard to justify the existence of NaN and the infinities.  I am in no way disputing that those values should be part of the IEEE standard or Java, so I'm not sure why you are pointing to that.  Also, "rounding toward zero" does not automatically explain the decision; such rounding is not well-defined mathematically.  Given the decision to round to *something* those are sensible choices, but it's not obvious that decision had to be made.

Comment: @Michael McGowan I guess I missunderstood your question. I had thought it was related to the fact of why floating-point operations in Java never throw exceptions. Now I realize you mean why downcasting floating- point special values does not throw a arithmetic exception.  I guess your question is applicable as well to "why integral data types do not throw exceptions upon overflow or underflow?" Because the thing is tha Java integral data types only throw exceptions when they face a division by zero. I do not know of a reason for these design choices either. Sorry for the missunderstanding.

Comment: @Michael McGowan Although you already accepted an answer, just out of curiosity I decided to read a bit more on the subject, and I found a couple of other references that you may find useful. I have edited my answer to include them. Perhaps this could help you on your quest for more details. Yet, I am sure this is not the answer you were looking for.

Comment: It's nice of the spec to say that it does the conversion of NaN to 0, but do they tell us why? Is it because originally it was "easier" bitwise somehow?  My guess is originally the JVM was easier to write if "native" operations like casting never threw any exceptions.  So I guess it was just an implementation detail.

Answer (score 4):

There is an ACM presentation from 1998 that still seems surprisingly current and brings some light: https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/JAVAhurt.pdf.

More concretely, regarding the surprising lack of exceptions when casting NaNs and infinities: see page 3, point 3: "Infinities and NaNs unleashed without the protection of floating-point traps and flags mandated by IEEE Standards 754/854 belie Java’s claim to robustness."

The presentation doesn't really answer the "why's", but does explain the consequences of the problematic design decisions in the Java language's implementation of floating point, and puts them in the context of the IEEE standards and even other implementations.

Answer (score 1):

It is in the JLS, see:
[JavaRanch post](http://www.coderanch.com/t/239753/java-programmer-SCJP/certification/cast-double-int)
http://www.coderanch.com/t/239753/java-programmer-SCJP/certification/cast-double-int
However a warning will be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Actually i think during some casting there are bit operations done (probably for perf issues?) so that you can have some unexpected behaviours. See what happens when you use >> and << operators.

For exemple:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    short test1 = (short)Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    System.out.println(test1);
    short test2 = (short)Integer.MAX_VALUE-1;
    System.out.println(test2);
    short test3 = (short)Integer.MAX_VALUE-2;
    System.out.println(test3);
    short test4 = (short)Double.MAX_VALUE-3;
    System.out.println(test4);
}
```

will output:

```
-1
-2
-3
-4
```