# Why does Math.round() return 0 for NaN arguments?

Tags: java, floating-point, nan

I thought that result of any mathematical operation on a NaN should give me a NaN back, but `Math.round(Float.NaN) == 0`

What is the rationale for such behavior of [Math.round()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28double%29)?

Curiously, C# behaves differently: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75ks3aby.aspx

Comment: as @pst has said, its the normal behavior defined for NaN: "If the argument is NaN, the result is 0".

Comment: The rationale is that there used to be a bug in `Math.round()` when called on NaN it could potentially ruin future calls to `Math.round()`: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4755500

Comment: The difference is likely to be; in Java it returns `long` which cannot be `Double.NaN` whereas an C# it returns a `double`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Haha. I want to smack myself in the head.

`Math.round(double)` returns a *long* and a *long* cannot be `NaN`. The alternative is an exception.

In C# the result is still a `double`.

Comment: The question is about rounding Floats

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Yes, `long Math.round(double)` is how it is defined in Java. This answer explains why it returns in `0` and not `NaN`. If it were `double Math.round(double)` then the C# way might be more appropriate...

Comment: @Hunter: The operation *returns* a `long`.

Comment: hah, funny (and a little sad).  Damn you, autoboxing (for confusing me)

Answer (score 28):

[`Math.round()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28double%29) is defined as `(long)Math.floor(a + 0.5d)`.

1. If `a` is `NaN`, then `a+0.5d` is `NaN`.
2. [`Math.floor()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floor%28double%29) is delagated to [`StrictMath.floor()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StrictMath.html#floor%28double%29) which returns `NaN` when passed in `NaN`.
3. When casting `NaN` to a `long`, it returns 0

So ultimately, it comes down to why casting `NaN` to a `long` returns 0. This issue has been thoroughly discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876369/why-does-casting-double-nan-to-int-not-throw-an-exception-in-java).

Comment: +1 for digging into the implementation a little! Have links to the [Open Source JDK] code for the appropriate functions?

Comment: +1 In Java 7 this definition has been dropped due to this issue [Why Math.round(0.499999999999999917) rounds to 1 on Java 6](http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/why-mathround0499999999999999917-rounds.html)