# Is NaN equal to 0?

Tags: java, nan

I tried this :

```
int x = (int)Math.sqrt(-1); //Math.sqrt(-1) returns NaN
System.out.println(x);
```

And the output is :

> 0

[This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) says that:

> Converting `NaN` to an integer type, or performing an integer operation whose floating-point equivalent would produce `NaN`, usually throws an exception. In Java, such operations throw instances of `java.lang.ArithmeticException`

But my code runs fine, **without** any exceptions, and the output is `0`.

Any reason for that?

Answer (score 3):

No, NaN is not equal to anything, including itself.

When casting NaN to `int`, the JVM will apply rounding toward zero. This explains the output of 0 you observe.

Comment: So why is my code giving the output `0`?

Comment: @Bathsheba Although this answers the question in title, providing explanation to the reason why the code snippet behaves the way mentioned would be helpful.

Comment: @Hackerdarshi The [question of which this question is a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876369/why-does-casting-double-nan-to-int-not-throw-an-exception-in-java) covers this.